# Performing a substring in C

Tags: c, substring

I am new to C and I am currently trying to get a substring of a string. The eventual goal is I have a string, which contains a set of numbers, i.e. 6218, and I keep taking a substring so I remove the last number, i.e.:

```
6218
621
62
6
```

At the moment I am hard coding the length I want to be, so as a start I am doing a substring of 4, expecting the result to still be 6218. However, its coming out at 62 when I print it in gdb.

Below is the code I am using.

```
char * performSearch(char * phoneNumber, int totalLookupNumberCount, numberLookupStruct *numberLookup, int maxCharsToLookup)
{
     int i;
    for (i = strlen(phoneNumber); i < maxCharsToLookup; i--)
    {
        char searchNumber[i+1];
        strncpy(searchNumber, phoneNumber, 4);
        searchNumber[i+1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

The function is called by the following:

```
char * displayName = performSearch(phoneNumber, totalLookupNumberCount, numberLookup, maxCharsToLookup);
```

I am stepping through the code in GDB so the very first thing I do, is print the searchNumber after the strncpy, therefore the loop doesn't actually get used.

I've checked the variables passed through and what strlen is returning and its correct

So in the code above I am expecting searchNumber to still be 6218, but it is outputting 62. Also just to be aware phoneNumber is passed to the function as char *.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: To 0-terminate the character array use: `searchNumber[i] = '\0';` Arrays in C are using a 0-based index.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and turn on your compiler's warnings ( `-Wall -Werror` for GCC is good when starting out).

Comment: @Mat if you're referring to the &searchNumber I did that as a test, I've actually removed it now and there no compiler warnings (there was with the & so warnings are on) but I am getting the same result

Comment: What is `phoneNumber`? Is it `"6218"`?

Comment: @jxh yes phone number is 6218

Comment: Provide more code or complete code-block if possible.

Comment: @VoidPointer please check the ammended question, I have added more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` test condition seems wrong:

```
for (i = strlen(phoneNumber); i < maxCharsToLookup; i--)
```

If `maxCharsToLookup` is larger than `strlen(phoneNumber)`, then it seems like this loop will do something funky when `i` becomes negative. If `maxCharsToLookup` is less than or equal to `strlen(phoneNumber)`, then the loop never starts. Probably you need something like this:

```
for (count = 0, i = strlen(phoneNumber);
     count < maxCharsToLookup && i > 0;
     ++count, --i)
```

`strncpy()` is hard to use. It will only NUL terminate the destination string if the source string has a shorter string length than the specified copy length. This is a hard rule to remember. In addition, it will always write the number of bytes you specified to write in the last parameter. In your code:

```
    char searchNumber[i+1];
    strncpy(searchNumber, phoneNumber, 4);
    searchNumber[i+1] = '\0';
```

If `i` is less than 3, `strncpy()` will overrun your buffer. This will lead to undefined behavior. You then set the byte after your buffer to NUL, which is also undefined. You should do something like this instead:

```
    char searchNumber[i+1];
    strncpy(searchNumber, phoneNumber, i);
    searchNumber[i] = '\0';
```

I prefer to use `snprintf()`. It always NUL terminates the resulting string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main () {
    char phoneNumber[] = "6218";
    for (int i = strlen(phoneNumber); i > 0; --i) {
        char searchNumber[i+1];
        snprintf(searchNumber, sizeof(searchNumber), "%s", phoneNumber);
        puts(searchNumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is having the same result, the search number is being set to 62 instead instead of 6218

Comment: Add a print statement in the `for` loop to check that `phoneNumber` and `searchNumber` is what you expect at each iteration. Compare with the sample program I provided, which gives me the expected output. http://ideone.com/eDw6q1 Without code to explicitly use `searchNumber`, the compiler may be optimizing it to do something else, and your debugger may be seeing that.

Comment: Yea it is working, I was looking at it via GDB and stepping through the code and printing it. But for some reason in GDB type ``print searchNumber`` will print ``$i = "62"``

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
string[i]=0;
```

This will put an end-of-string character just after the specified point, cutting off the rest of the string.